# days inaccurate in year one

Tags: python, datetime

I wrote the below code to give me a certain day at the end of the year in which the pay periods for the year begin. For some reason it is telling me that dec 22, 1 (the year one) was on a Saturday. Online calendars tell me it was on a Thursday.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def pp_firstday(year):
    print(type(year))
    firstday = datetime(1,12,22,0,0,0)
    yr = 2
    print(yr, " ", firstday.strftime("%b/%d/%Y  %a"))
    yr = 3
    while int(firstday.strftime("%Y")) != year-1:
        firstday += timedelta(weeks=52)
        if int(firstday.strftime("%m")) <= 12 and int(firstday.strftime("%d")) <= 12:
            firstday += timedelta(weeks=2)
            print("27: ",firstday.strftime("%b/%d/%Y  %a"))
        print(yr, " ",firstday.strftime("%b/%d/%Y  %a"))
        yr += 1
    return firstday

year = int(input("Year >>>")) result=pp_firstday(year) print(result.strftime("%b/%d/%Y  %a"))
```

The problem is that when you run this the output shows:
2   Dec/22/0001  Sat
Python thinks Dec 22nd, year 1 was a Saturday. 
By the time we get to 2019 the output shows: 
2020   Dec/21/2019  Sat
thus the problem is corrected. 
What gives?

Comment: I have a feeling the answer to this question is that, somewhere down the line in history, someone changed the standards and we skipped either forward or back a few weekdays. I don't have thorough enough knowledge to know when that might have been, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [`calendar` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html):

> Most of these functions and classes rely on the datetime module which
>   uses an idealized calendar, **the current Gregorian calendar
>   indefinitely extended in both directions.** This matches the definition
>   of the “proleptic Gregorian” calendar in Dershowitz and Reingold’s
>   book “Calendrical Calculations”, where it’s the base calendar for all
>   computations.

December 22, 1 was a Thursday in the [Julian calendar](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/custom.html?year=1&country=23&cols=3&doy=1&df=1), which was used back then. However, it's a Saturday in the [proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1&country=22)